# Is it possible to host Discourse on a Raspberry PI

Tags: web-server

Any one tried to host discourse (http://www.discourse.org/) on a raspberry pi? Or is there any issue that cannot be solved on a pie?

Comment: Why don't you try it and ask for help when you get stuck?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do it, given that Discourse is just a Ruby on Rails application.  It **will** run slowly, given that Rails, Redis, and Postgres will all be sharing the limited processing power and RAM, but it *should* work.

Answer (score 3):

No currently you cannot host discourse on Raspberry Pi 2

Install Ubuntu OK

Install Swapfile OK

Install Docker FAIL

- Error: you are not using a 64bit platform.
Docker currently only supports 64bit platforms.

ARMV7 is 32 bit

Comment: It is not required to use Docker in order to use Discourse, it is just *currently* the recommended way.  Installing Discourse by hand is still entirely doable.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that Discourse requires 1GB of memory to compile all the prerequisites, so it's unlikely to run on the Pi. This is according to the following Guide, [Installing Discourse on Ubuntu](http://install-discourse.org/).

Comment: If you look on the [discourse meta site](http://meta.discourse.org/t/stack-requirements-for-a-diy-discourse/803/12), there are people who get it working with less than 1GB.  You just need to configure it to use only 1 or 2 `thin` workers.  I would assume that processing power is the bigger issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM cloud provider Scaleway adopted the building scripts to run Discourse on their platform. You do not need docker to run Discourse, however, there are some dependencies on x86/64-only libraries. Scaleway got around these issues by [monkey-patching](https://github.com/scaleway/image-app-discourse).

To install discourse, one has to follow the now unsupported installation guide for ubuntu: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-ubuntu.md

Answer (score 0):

You can probably run it by [following guide](https://meta.discourse.org/t/beginners-guide-to-install-discourse-on-ubuntu-for-development/14727).

I'm trying to do so, and facing a problem of installing `mini_racer` (`libv8`) gem on `armv7l`. If it can be solved, I don't see any other problems with running Discourse on a Raspberry Pi.

This information may be useful:

- https://meta.discourse.org/t/beginners-guide-to-install-discourse-on-ubuntu-for-development/14727
- https://meta.discourse.org/t/hosting-discourse-on-a-raspberry-pi-3/54891
- https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/226

Answer (score 0):

Official support was just added this week. The official install works on a Raspberry Pi running arm64 out of the box now.

Check https://blog.discourse.org/2021/12/2021-12-07-discourse-on-a-raspberry-pi/ for more details.